# Disable IE11 resize controls inside contenteditable divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, contenteditable

Inside a `contenteditable` div, IE11 adds some resizing controls on elements.
Is there a way to disable these?

The resizing tools that I want to remove:

[image]

The HTML inside the `contenteditable` div:

[image]

**Note:** this is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635319/2256325), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21875990/2256325), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635319/2256325) questions.
I have tried solutions suggested there with no sucess.

CKEditor has [a issue about this](http://ckeditor.com/comment/136441#comment-136441) and with apparent no solution.

**Any recent discoveries into this bug?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864047/how-to-disable-elements-selection-and-resizing-in-contenteditable-div

Comment: @ChrisStanley that question is linked in my question also/already. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You should not ask again the same question if no suitable solution has been provided, because duplicate questions are discouraged. Instead, you may offer a **bounty**.

Comment: @vsync did you notice this question is 3 years old and that I linked other questions in my question? :)

Comment: Yes i did notice